# bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `>'

Tags: linux

Siguiendo una guía de [esta pagina](https://blog.g0tmi1k.com/dvwa/bruteforce-medium/) encontré el siguiente comando:

```
for loop in {1..3}; do
for> echo -e "\nLoop: $loop"
for> date; curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
for>   curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
for>   curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
for>   curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
for>   curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null && date
for> sleep 30s
for> done
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

> bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `>'

¿Qué es lo que esta mal?

Comment: Diria que tienes que borrar todos esos `for>` pues no tienen sentido... prueba y dinos que tal

Comment: Sale el siguiente error `bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado done`

Comment: Acabo de mirar de donde lo has copiado, y veo que delante del primer `for` tienen una almoadilla `#`... si tu tambien la tienes quitala y prueba de nuevo

Comment: La ejecute sin la almohadilla, ya esta la solución, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No veo diferencia entre la respuesta aceptada y mi comentario. No se porque no te ha funcionado. Algo debias hacer distinto. En fin, me alegro que ya te funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `for>` no son parte del código fuente. Te está indicando que el `for` de la primera línea no ha terminado`.

```
for loop in {1..3}; do
    echo -e "\nLoop: $loop"
    date; curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
    curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
    curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
    curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null & \
    curl -s -b 'security=medium' -b dvwa.cookie 'http://192.168.1.44/DVWA/vulnerabilities/brute/?username=user&password=pass&Login=Login' >/dev/null && date
    sleep 30s
done
```

Comment: Así que eso era, gracias, funciona!